# Python Web Scraping not working

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm new to Python and am trying to do some web scraping. I'm trying to get things like Deck Name, Username, Elixir Cost, and Card from a website about the game Clash Royale. I am taking the data and then sending it into a folder called "Data" in my project directory. The files are being created fine but I am getting empty brackets [] in each .json file. I don't know what I am doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks! Code is below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import uuid
import json
import os.path
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as Threadpool


def getdata(url):
    save_path=r'/Users/crazy4byu/PycharmProjects/Final/Data'
    clashlist=[]
    html = requests.get(url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html5lib')
    clash = soup.find_all('div',{'class':'row result'})
    for clashr in clash:
        clashlist.append(
                {
                    'Deck Name':clashr.find('a').text,
                    'User':clashr.find('td',{'class':'user center'}).text,
                    'Elixir Cost':clashr.find('span',{'class':'elixir_cost'}).text,
                    'Card':clashr.find('span',{'class':None}).text
                }
        )

    decks = soup.find_all('div',{'class':' row result'})
    for deck in decks:
        clashlist.append(
                {
                    'Deck Name':clashr.find('a').text,
                    'User':clashr.find('td',{'class':'user center'}).text,
                    'Elixir Cost':clashr.find('span',{'class':'elixir_cost'}).text,
                    'Card':clashr.find('span',{'class':None}).text

                }
        )

    with open(os.path.join(save_path,'data_'+str(uuid.uuid1())+'.json'),'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(clashlist,outfile)


if'__main__' == __name__:
    urls=[]
    urls.append(r'http://clashroyaledeckbuilder.com/clashroyale/deckViewer/highestRated')
    for i in range(20,990,10):
        urls.append(r'http://clashroyaledeckbuilder.com/clashroyale/deckViewer/highestRated'+str(i))

    pool = Threadpool(25)
    pool.map(getdata, urls)

    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Comment: The url you are looking at is not valid.

http://clashroyaledeckbuilder.com/clashroyale/deckViewer/highestRated/?page=1

And paginate over page=0,1,2,3...etc

Comment: Okay, so would this work for the last part? I'm still not getting any data...
`if'__main__' == __name__:
    urls=[]
    urls.append(r'http://clashroyaledeckbuilder.com/clashroyale/deckViewer/highestRated')
    for i in range(20,990,10):
        urls.append(r'http://clashroyaledeckbuilder.com/clashroyale/deckViewer/highestRated/?page='+str(i))

    pool = Threadpool(25)
    pool.map(getdata, urls)`

Comment: We don't have much information to debug this. If the files are being created and you are getting empty brackets, then your clashlist is empty. Why is your clashlist empty? Well either your decks variable or clash variable are an empty list. Put some debug statements in and see what happens. 

Note: if debugging a multiprocessed app is hard (it is!) then make it a single process. Then once you have that working add back in the multiprocessing.

Comment: So I found that the class in the soup.find_all statement was wrong so I changed that to `clash = soup.find_all('tr',{'class':'deck link'})` but I got an error when I ran it saying: "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'" I took the ".text" off of everything (honestly, I don't know what that does) and ran it again and I'm getting another error: "TypeError: <span class="elixir_cost">4.3</span> is not JSON serializable" What does that mean?

Comment: You should read the errors they are informative!
"NoneType object has no attribute text" means you are trying to access the text method on the None object. IE: one of your find functions is returning None because it isn't finding anything. In order to find out which one, either use a debugger or some judicious print statements.

The .text functions returns the text contained in that <span> object. When you removed the text function then you're trying to dump as json an object that is not json serializable and you get an error.